# Ionic Native: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: cordova, ionic2, inappbrowser, typescript-typings

I am following Ionic-Native's usage for Cordoava's InAppBrowse r plugin (http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/inappbrowser/). The only problem is when I go to construct the InAppBrowser object (`let browser = new InAppBrowser(url, '_system')`) I get the following TypeScript error:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

This is not the first time I have run into this TypeScript error using Ionic 2 / Ionic-Native and I am wondering if I need to update my typings somehow or if the documentation Ionic is providing is outdated. Any Information would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when the number of parameters supplied in the function is not as per the required number of parameters. Also the document seems to be different. Please try to include inappbrowser as follows. Guess this will work.

```
import {InAppBrowser} from 'ionic-native';

let browser = InAppBrowser.open(url,"_system");
```

**Update in ionic version 2.3.0**

After the adding the inAppBrowser plugin, install the npm typings for the same

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

And use it in your ts file.

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

constructor(private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser) { }
...
const browser = this.inAppBrowser.create('https://ionic.io');
```

Comment: What you put above is exactly what I have. Also, my url variable is appropriatly a string

Comment: Do you mean that you tried calling "open" method of InAppBrowser? But In your question you have created an InAppBrowser object with varaibles.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with cordova plugin code, in iOS it is still installing old code but in Android it download latest one.

Please use `InAppBrowser.open(url,"_system", "location=yes")` for iOS build, for me it worked.